# Learnings AJAX in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am trying to figure out how to write an AJAX function, and haven't been able to find a tutorial that's not over my head.

My HTML is:

```
<a href="{% url pay_provider id=statement.statement_id %}" id="pay_provider">Pay</a>
```

When a user clicks "Pay", the following django would be executed via AJAX:

```
def pay_provider(request, statement_id):
    FinancialStatements.objects.get(statement_id=statement_id).update(paid=1)
    return redirect(...)
```

What would be the necessary url.py, views.py, and js in order to do this at the most basic level?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the documentation around [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) and possibly Python's [JSON library](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) or even using something like [jQuery](http://jQuery.com) which will help with cross browser issues.

Comment: @David542 : Looking over your comments and re-reading the question, I think there is some confusion (some of which I addressed at the start of my answer).  What is the order of events and the overall goal of this transaction?  Are you trying to get the value for the `href` or is the `href` the ajax responder? Are you needing to pass info to the script other than triggering it? Something that would help *a lot* would be if you could show us a) what the URL of the href (not the real one, just not the pre-compiled like your example) and b) confirm if that URL is what you're ajax request is going.

Comment: @Anthony: I'm not sure I understand your point a), but I am trying to do a straight ajax request, not re-load the page. I think my above href is wrong (should it be `href="#;"`). I just don't know enough about AJAX yet to know otherwise.

Comment: @David542 So the questions are : 1) Is the href in the link the address of the remote script you are trying to send this ajax request 2) if not, where are you getting the URL for the remote server, 3) do you need to pass any data to the remote server? and 4) Are you expecting something back from the remote server?  We can pretend it's PHP,PYTHON or QBASIC.  It's more important to know what is being sent and where you are getting the address to send that data.

Comment: @Anthony I updated my code a bit to show what I am trying to do (not using AJAX). The url is the site's url, so `www.example.com` (in this case, localhost). Yes, what I need back in the response will be the FinancialStatement.paid value (in this case = 1).

Comment: @David542 - Which URL is the site's URL, the href URL or the one that you need to post to (or both?).  change the href URL in your example to a real URL (example.com/whatever) is fine, but something along the lines of what actually get's output. That's where I'm unable to tell which way is up or down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've got a couple of issues:

1. You don't have any ajax.
2. You don't have any jquery.
3. From what I can tell, you are using an `a` element to fire an ajax event. This isn't a horrible idea, but it has overhead you may want to avoid.

Finally, am I reading your `href` correctly in that you are setting it to the script that returns the ajax response?  Or are you trying to get it so that when they click on the link, it takes them to a new page while simultaneously sending an ajax request?

If it's the latter, I'd avoid it. If it's the URL of the ajax responder, try this:

#### HTML/Python:

```
<a href="{% url pay_provider id=statement.statement_id %}" id="pay_provider">Pay</a>
```

#### JQuery:

```
$("#pay_provider").on("click" function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // Prevent browser from following link.
    post_url = $("this").attr("href");
    $.post(post_url, function(data) {
         // do whatever with the returned data.
    });
});
```

By setting the `post_url` right after the event handler, it avoids issues with `$(this)` getting overwritten by the `post()` function and allows you to store your ajax URL in the link.  While this could be an issue for browsers that don't play nice, it does offer the benefit of reusing the same ajax function for several such links, for example:

```
<a href="{% url pay_provider id=statement.statement_id %}" 
class="provider_action">Pay</a>
<a href="{% url save_provider id=statement.statement_id %}" 
class="provider_action">Save</a>
<a href="{% url cancel_provider id=statement.statement_id %}" 
class="provider_action">Cancel</a>
```

Now you can do:

```
$(".provider_action").on("click" function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();  // Prevent browser from following link.
    post_url = $("this").attr("href");
    $.post(post_url, function(data) {
         // do whatever with the returned data.
    });
});
```

Which will work on all 3 "action" links, but fire their own action script.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the href to that URL, the browser is going to make a request to the URL synchronously.  You can use jQuery to use the link's click event to make an ajax request.

```
$(function() {
    $('#pay_provider').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('{% url pay_provider id=statement.statement_id %}', function() {
            // alert('ajax call complete');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How would I pull the variable `statement.statement_id` in this case (from an external file)?

Comment: @David542 Unfortunately, I don't know enough (read "anything at all") about django to answer that.  The client side code I gave you will cause the browser to make the ajax request, but I don't know how django will work with the request on the server.

Comment: stopping propagation should not be the default. This could result in additional event handlers not being fired that are bound to the event. e.preventDefault() placed at the top of the method body will prevent the default behavior of the browser, without eliminating/stopping other event handlers from firing

Comment: @David542 - I also know nothing about Python or Django, but are you asking how you are going to get statement.statement_id from the ajax call or how you are going to get it into the `href` to begin with before the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most basic example I could come up with. It covers add/delete function:

HTML:

```
<select name="test_add" id="test_add">
    {% for position in all_positions %}
    <option value="{{ position.id }}">{{ position }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

{% for position in user_positions %}
    <span id="positions">
        {{ position }}
        <input type="hidden" class="position_id" value="{{ position.id }}">
        <a class="delete-position" href="#;">X</a>
    </span>
{% endfor %}
```

URLs:

```
                        url(r'^ajax_test_delete/$',
                            'ajax_test_delete',
                            name='ajax_test_delete'),

                        url(r'^ajax_test_add/$',
                            'ajax_test_add',
                            name='ajax_test_add'),

                        url(r'^ajax_test_page/$',
                            'ajax_test_page',
                            name='ajax_test_page'),
```

Views:

```
def ajax_test_page(request):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    all_positions = Position.objects.all_with_gender().filter(id__lt=50).order_by('position')
    user_positions = profile.positions.order_by('positiontimestamp__timestamp')
    return render(request, 'videos/ajax_test_page.html', {'user_positions': user_positions, 'all_positions': all_positions})

def ajax_test_delete(request):
    position_id = int(request.POST['position_id'])
    position = Position.objects.get(id=position_id)
    profile = request.user.get_profile
    PositionTimestamp.objects.get(profile=profile, position=position).delete()
    return HttpResponse()

def ajax_test_add(request):
    position_id = int(request.POST['position_id'])
    position = Position.objects.get(id=position_id)
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    add_new = PositionTimestamp(profile=profile, position=position)
    add_new.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

JS:

```
// TEST AJAX //
$("a.delete-position").live('click', function(){
   // use named variables in the outer function -- $(this) refers to the response in the inner function
   var span = $(this).parent();
   var position_id = $(this).siblings('input.position_id').val();
   $.post('/ajax_test_delete/', {'position_id': position_id}, function(response) {
       span.remove();       
   });
});

$("#test_add").change(function(){
    var position_id = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $.post('/ajax_test_add/', {'position_id': position_id}, function(response) {
        var position_name = $("#test_add option:selected").text();
        var span = $('<span>' + position_name + '</span>');
        span.append($('<input type="hidden" class="position_id" value="' + position_id + '">' ));
        span.append($('<a class="delete-position" href="#;">X</a>'));
        $('#positions').append($(span));   
    });
});
```